# Windows Phone 7 and Sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, sharepoint-2010, wss-3.0

Do I need to install/configuge the (entire and expensive) Windows Sharepoint Server (is the 2007 version sufficient?) or am I fine with Sharepoint Services 3.0 in order to work with the sharepoint workspace in the office hub on Windows Phone 7?

Thanks, David

Answer (score 1):

You should be okay using [SharePoint 2010 Foundation](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=49c79a8a-4612-4e7d-a0b4-3bb429b46595&displaylang=en).  It's free for just the [basics](http://sharepoint.microsoft.com/en-us/buy/Pages/Editions-Comparison.aspx).

Comment: What do I do when my server is too "old" and doesn't meet the system requirements of SharePoint 2010 Foundation (neither being 64-bit nor having 4 cores)? Thanks!

Comment: Unfortunately, you're going to have to get a new server because [Windows Phone 7 only integrates with SharePoint 2010](http://techdhaan.wordpress.com/2011/02/18/windows-phone-7-enterprise-support5-reasons-to-wait/).

Answer (score 1):

To expand on what Scott said, SharePoint Workspace (Windows or Windows Phone 7) only works with SharePoint 2010 versions.

You can certainly run a small SharePoint 2010 Foundation on less then 4 cores, but 64bit is a requirement.

Office 365 due out this year is a paid hosted service running SharePoint 2010 that -should in theory- support SharePoint Workspace the same as on-premise.

SkyDrive, the Microsoft consumer service similar to Google Docs, is said to start supporting Windows Phone 7 as storage for Office files once the phone OS gets an update later this year.